# Erro ao validar com Regex

Tags: c#, regex

Estou tentando formatar este texto com regex mas não tenho o retorno desejado:

De:

> "ST STN, CONJUNTO J, *  LOJAS T-40 /T41,  - TER-REO, SHOPPING &
> BOULEVARD KM 28,5   VALOR 450.00 CENTRAL."

Para:

> "ST STN CONJUNTO J LOJAS T40 T41 TERREO SHOPPING E BOULEVARD KM 28,5
> 450.00 CENTRAL"

## Meu código:

```
String padrao = @"(?i)(,|.)?[^A-Za-z0-9]\s"; String padrao =
@"(?i)[^0-9a-z]\s]";
 
Regex rg = new Regex(_texto, " ");
 
var arrayTexto =
resultado.Normalize(NormalizationForm.Formd).toCharArray();
foreach(char letter in arrayTexto) { if
(CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(letter) !=
UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark) sb.Append(letter); }
```

O que há de errado?

Comment: você quer remover `*, -`?

Comment: Aparentemente é isso mesmo, um `replace` vai resolver.

Comment: @Ismael bem pensado.

Comment: Isso!, remover caracteres especiais, ponto, ecomercial e onde for KM e valores manter a virgula e o ponto.

Comment: @AdrianoSUV já tentou com Replace?

Comment: Replace vai ficar muito complexo pois tenho que eliminar todos caracteres especiais e acentos e preservar o ponto e virgula onde for valores e quiometragem.

Comment: Se eu conseguir tirar o **Ponto** e preservar a **Virgula** desse endereço AV D.R MAURO L MONTEIRO KM 28,5  com **Regex** o restante posso fazer um **Replace** nativo do csharp.

Answer (score 0):

Aconselho você a usar o `replace` como citado pelo usuário @Marconi

Acho válido lembrar que uma coisa dificulta muito o seu caso, você quer eliminar vários carácteres especiais (`-,*/&`) e deixar alguns em pontos específicos como nos dígitos após KM, isso dificulta muito criar uma lógica geral que vai resolver seu problema.

Porém se deseja continuar usando regex, você pode utilizar vários OU's (`|`)para os casos, deixando o mais raro no começo.

```
(\d*\.\d*?|\d*,\d|\w*|\s)
```

A regex acima vai capturar tudo que você deseja, ela verifica primeiro o caso da sequencia ser dígitos seguidos de `.` com dígitos após para satisfazer o caso (450.00) depois verifica se a sequencia é dígito seguido de `,` dígito depois verifica os casos de caracteres não especiais sendo minúsculos ou maiúsculos e depois verifica se esses caracteres são espaços.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez este regex possa te atender

```
string pattern = @"(?i)(,|\.)?[^a-z0-9]\s|(\/|\-)";
```

Utilizando o Regex.Replace() dá pra remover os caracteres especiais.

```
private static string PreprocessingText(string input)
{
    string pattern = @"(?i)(,|\.)?[^a-z0-9]\s|(\/|\-)";
    return Regex.Replace(input, pattern, " ");
}
```

Veja funcionando no [.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/giY50B)